# Selenium/Cucumber/TestNG Automation - NPE for driver instance in parent class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I am pretty new to automation and have been learning Cucumber framework with Selenium and TestNG. I have been learning about the concept of using hooks. I realize that when i try to pass the driver instance back from the hook to the Base Test class, I'm doing something wrong and so the getDriver() class in Base Test class returns null. I have posted my classes below, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Hooks class**

```
package StepDefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import utilities.BaseTest;

public class Hooks extends BaseTest{
    
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        openBrowser();
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        closeBrowser();
    }
    

}
```

**BaseTest class**

```
package utilities;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import dataProviders.ConfigFileReader;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;


public class BaseTest{
    
    public WebDriver driver;
    ConfigFileReader config = new ConfigFileReader();
    
    
    public void openBrowser() {
        
        switch(config.getBrowser())
        {
        case CHROME:
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        case FIREFOX:
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
            
        case EDGE:
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
            break;
        
        }   
        

    }
    
    
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
    
    public void navigateToSite(String str) {
        driver.navigate().to(str);
    }
    
    public void waitForPageToLoad()
    {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(config.getImplicitWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(config.getPageLoadTimeout(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
        
    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        if(null != driver) {
            System.out.println("Executing close");
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**Step definition file -- GoogleSearchSteps.java**

```
package StepDefinitions;




//import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import dataProviders.ConfigFileReader;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;


import pages.*;
import utilities.BaseTest;


public class GoogleSearchSteps extends BaseTest {

    googlesearch gs;
    ConfigFileReader configFileReader;


    @Given("browser window is open")
    public void browser_is_open() {
    
    gs = new googlesearch(getDriver());
        waitForPageToLoad();        
        configFileReader= new ConfigFileReader();
    }

    @And("user is on google search page")
    public void user_is_on_google_search_page() {
        
        System.out.println("Inside Step - user is on goolge search page");
        
        navigateToSite(configFileReader.getApplicationUrl());
        
    }

    @When("user enters a text in search box")

    public void user_enters_a_text_in_search_box() throws InterruptedException {
        
        System.out.println("Inside Step - user enters a text in search box");
        
        gs.enterSearchTerm(configFileReader.getSearchTerm());
        
        
    }

    @And("hits enter")
    public void hits_enter() throws InterruptedException {
        
        System.out.println("Inside Step - hits enter");
        
        gs.hitEnterForSearchTerm();
        
    }

    @Then("user is navigated to search results")
    public void user_is_navigated_to_search_results() {
        
        System.out.println("Inside Step - user is navigated to search results");
        
        gs.getPageSource(configFileReader.getPageSource()); 
        
        
    
    }




}
```

`getDriver()` method of BaseTest returns a null

Comment: Can you uncomment `//import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;` and retest?

Comment: Thanks but that did not help because I am not declaring a webdriver instance in the step definition file.

Comment: Solved this by making the driver variable static in the BaseTest class